# Continue if response is 'yes'

Tags: bash

I have a script which checks for the existence of a directory and runs the following:

```
 if [ -d /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME ]; then
     echo "Directory '$TABLENAME' already exists. Delete the existing directory?"
     select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
         case $yn in
             Yes )    rm -rf /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME
                      break;;
             No )    echo "$EXIT"
                     exit 1;;
         esac
     done
 else
 echo "Please enter the email you would like the results to be sent to:"
 read RECIPIENT
 mkdir /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME
```

Following this, there are several more lines of code which populates the directory with csv files. The problem I'm having is that I want the script to proceed to the mkdir command if they select "yes".

So far, the break command provides a partial fix - if "yes" is selected twice in succession, then it deletes the directory and then proceeds to recreate it. This is what currently happens when I try to run the script:

```
+ '[' -d /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/banks ']'
+ echo 'Directory '\''banks'\'' already exists. Overwrite the existing directory?'
Directory 'banks' already exists. Overwrite the existing directory?
+ select yn in '"Yes"' '"No"'
1) Yes
2) No
#? 1
+ case $yn in
+ rm -rf /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/banks
+ break 1
#? 1
+ case $yn in
+ '[' -d /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/banks ']'
+ echo 'Please enter the email you would like the results to be sent to:'
Please enter the email you would like the results to be sent to:
+ read RECIPIENT
dummyemail@gmail.com
+ mkdir /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/banks
```

I would like a solution where, if "yes" is selected, then it deletes the directory and then proceeds to the line following, but otherwise exits if "no" is selected.

EDIT: Figured out the source of the problem - the break is actually bringing me back to another yesno query I ran right before it. I just need to figure out a way to prevent the break from bringing me back to the original yesno - This example should help illustrate the problem.

```
echo "Proceed?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
                Yes )   echo "Creating new directory for 'banks'..."
                        if [ -d /home/banks ]; then
                                echo "Delete the existing directory?"
                                select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                                        case $yn in
                                                Yes)    rm -r /home/banks
                                                        break;;
                                                No )    echo "Exit Status 1"
                                                        exit 1;;
                                        esac
                                done
                        else
                                echo "Proceeding..."
                                mkdir /home/banks
                                echo "Proceeded to next step."
                                exit 1
                        fi;;
                No )    echo "Exit Status 2"
                        exit 1;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: So what does this script do that is incorrect? It looks to me that if a user selects Yes, directory is deleted, the loop breaks and the directory is created. If the user selects no, the script exits. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what happens - I'm still fairly new to bash - but the first time the user selects "yes", it simply presents a new line. It's only when they select "yes" again that the loop breaks and proceeds to create the directory. If I would guess, then the first "yes" executes the command to remove the directory, and the second one returns us to the line above (which checks for the directory), finds that it no longer exists, and then ignores the loop.

Comment: Your sample output has the directory check happening twice. It must be inside a loop of some kind. Any reason you can't post the entire script?

Comment: Try changing the `exit 1;;` in the select to a `break;;` (same as in yes) and follow the suggestion of miken32 to remove the `else` and replace it with an `fi`.

Comment: Apologies, I had to step out for a bit. I tried to replicate the results with a test scenario, and think I understand the problem now - when I break the loop, it's actually returning to another yesno statement around the entire thing, which is what the second line is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the code that makes the directory inside an `else` statement. As long as the directory exists, it will never get to that command. Try this (just replacing `else` with `fi`.)

```
if [ -d /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME ]; then
     echo "Directory '$TABLENAME' already exists. Delete the existing directory?"
     select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
         case $yn in
             Yes )    rm -rf /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME
                      break;;
             No )    echo "$EXIT"
                     exit 1;;
         esac
     done
 fi
 echo "Please enter the email you would like the results to be sent to:"
 read RECIPIENT
 mkdir /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME
```

For the record, this is how I would do the same bit of script:

```
if [ -d "/home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME" ]; then
    read -n 1 -p "Directory '$TABLENAME' already exists. Delete the existing directory? " YN
    if [ $YN != "Y" -a $YN != "y" ]; then
        echo "$EXIT"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
read -p "Please enter the email you would like the results to be sent to: " RECIPIENT
mkdir "/home/philip_lee/csv_dump/$TABLENAME"
```

Always quote variables; it's unlikely there will be a space in what I assume is a database table name, but it's good practice anyway. `read` accepts a prompt as part of the command, and doesn't force you into a control structure like `select` does. `case` seems like overkill for two options (and personally, I hate the syntax!)

Comment: Gave this a try - still getting the same response:

Directory 'banks' already exists. Overwrite the existing directory?

1) Yes
2) No
#? 1
#? 1
 >>proceeds to execute rest of script.

Comment: Your sample code above has the prompt "Delete the existing directory" but here you say "Overwrite the existing directory." Sure everyone's looking at the same block of code?

Comment: Ah, that's just an echo. I use the term 'overwrite' for the user's benefit...I guess that's a little confusing. I'll reword that.

Comment: This was actually part of the solution to a larger problem which I had in my code - it eventually worked itself into the fix (among a bunch of other things), so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve the issue by separating out the yes/no loops in this way:

```
echo "Proceed?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
                Yes )   break;;
                No )    echo "Exiting...Status 1"
                        exit 1;;
        esac
done
echo "Creating new directory for 'banks'..."
if [ -d /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/banks ]; then
        echo "Directory 'banks' already exists. Delete the existing directory?"
        select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                case $yn in
                        Yes)    rm -r /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/banks
                                break;;
                        No )    echo "Exiting...Status 2"
                                exit 1;;
                esac
        done
fi
echo "Proceeding..."
mkdir /home/philip_lee/csv_dump/banks
echo "Proceeded to next step."
exit 1
```

Looks cleaner now, too - thanks to everybody who responded.